# How to use Scatter/Gather IO in Boost Asio for sending a struct containing a vector?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, ipc, boost-asio

I am trying to build a simple IPC protocol using Boost Asio where the server side will be sending a struct that contains a `vector<uint8_t>` to the client. I was suggested to use a scatter/gather IO approach, but I can't get it working, as it seems the client is only receiving part of the data it is expecting and it keeps waiting indefinitely for the rest of the data to arrive even though it should already be there.
This is what I have right now:

```cpp
// File: client.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "ipc_common.hpp"

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ba::io_context io;

    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

    switch (args.size()) {
        case 1:
            args = {args.at(0), "localhost", "6869"};
            break;
        case 2:
            args = {args.at(0), args.at(1), "6869"};
            break;
        case 3:
            args = {args.at(0), args.at(1), args.at(2)};
            break;
        default:
            std::clog << "usage: " << args.at(0) << " [host = localhost] [port = 6869]" << std::endl;
            return 1;
    }

    try {
        propertiesPacket properties;
        properties.val1 = 9;
        properties.val2 = 45;

        tcp::socket socket(io);
        tcp::resolver resolver(io);

        connect(socket, resolver.resolve(args.at(1), args.at(2)));
        write(socket, ba::buffer(&properties, sizeof(properties)));

        uint16_t responseSize {};
        ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(&responseSize, sizeof(uint16_t)));

        std::clog << "client responseSize: " << responseSize << std::endl;
        processedData response {};

        std::vector<ba::mutable_buffer> responseBuffers {
            ba::buffer(&response.size, sizeof(uint16_t)),
            ba::buffer(&response.values, responseSize - sizeof(uint8_t))
        };
        ba::read(socket, responseBuffers);

        std::clog << response.serialize();

        return 0;
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::clog << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

```cpp
// File: server.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "ipc_common.hpp"

namespace ba = boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using TCPSocket = tcp::socket;

class ServerConnection
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ServerConnection>
{
    public:
        ServerConnection(TCPSocket socket)
            : socket_(std::move(socket))
        { }


        void start()
        {
            std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            doRead();
        }


    private:
        void doRead()
        {
            std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            auto self(shared_from_this());
            socket_.async_read_some(ba::buffer(&properties_, sizeof(properties_)),
                                    [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                                    {
                                        std::clog << "received " << length << std::endl;
                                        if (!ec) {
                                            processData();
        
                                            std::vector<ba::const_buffer> msg {
                                                ba::buffer(&filePacketSize_, sizeof(uint16_t)),
                                                ba::buffer(&filePacket_.val, sizeof(filePacket_.val)),
                                                ba::buffer(&filePacket_.values, sizeof(filePacket_.values))};
                                            std::clog << "filePacketSize_: " << filePacketSize_ << std::endl;

                                            ba::async_write(socket_, msg,
                                                            [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, std::size_t length)
                                                            {
                                                                std::clog << "written " << length << std::endl;
                                                                if (!ec) doRead();
                                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
        }


        void processData()
        {
            filePacket_.val = properties_.val1;

            // Just for demonstration, we fill the vector with random values
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 re(rd()) ;
            std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> dist(0, 255);
            for (size_t i {}; i < filePacket_.val; ++i) {
                processedData.values.push_back(dist(re));
            }
        }

        TCPSocket socket_;

        propertiesPacket properties_;
        processedData filePacket_;
        uint16_t filePacketSize_;
};

class Server
{
    public:
        using IOContext = ba::io_context;
        using TCPAcceptor = tcp::acceptor;

        Server(IOContext& io, uint16_t port)
            : socket_(io),
              acceptor_(io, {tcp::v4(), port})
        {
            doAccept();
        }

    private:
        void doAccept()
        {
            std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
            acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
                [this](error_code ec)
                {
                    if (!ec) {
                        std::clog << "Accepted " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                        std::make_shared<ServerConnection>(std::move(socket_))->start();
                        doAccept();
                    }
                    else {
                        std::clog << "Accept " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    }
                });
        }

        TCPSocket socket_;
        TCPAcceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

    switch (args.size()) {
        case 1:
            args = {args.at(0), "6869"};
            break;
        case 2:
            args = {args.at(0), args.at(1)};
            break;
        default:
            std::clog << "usage: " << args.at(0) << " [port = 6869]" << std::endl;
            return 1;
    }
    
    try {
        ba::io_context io;
        Server server(io, std::stoi(args.at(1)));
        
        io.run();
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::clog << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
// File: ipc_common.hpp

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct propertiesPacket
{
    uint8_t val1;
    uint8_t val2;
};

struct processedData
{
    uint8_t val;
    std::vector<uint8_t> values;

    std::string serialize()
    {
        std::stringstream sstream;
        sstream << "val: " << (unsigned int)val << std::endl;
        for (const auto &i : values)
        {
            sstream << i << " ";
        }
        
        sstream << std::endl;
        return sstream.str();
    }
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample seems corrupted.

1. For one, `args.at(3)` and `args.at(4)` will by definition always throw, because by definition the switch statement earlier will always exit the client when there are more than 2 command line arguments (`default:`).
2. Secondly, the client `read` uses `&response.size` but no such member exists at all.
3. Thirdly, server `processData` uses a `.val` property of `procesedData` which isn't even a member (it's a type, likely should be `filePacket_.val` instead).
4. Fourthly, it assigns that from `properties_.val;` which ALSO doesn't exist at all (there's only `val1` and `val2`).
5. Next up, `rd` isn't used to initialize the URBG (random engine, `re`). Instead it calls an unknown identifier named `random_device()`. Likely ought to be `rd()` instead.
6. Again, where it sais `processedData.val` you probably meant `filePacket_.val`
7. And where you write `processedData.push_back(...)` you probably meant to say `filePacket_.values.push_back(...)`...
8. There's a spurious `;` behind `void doAccept()` in the Server
9. By contrast, the `;` is missing after each struct definition in `ipc_common.hpp`
10. The `processedData` struct defines a `serialize()` method that is never used. It also uses a C-style cast where `static_cast<unsigned>(val)` would be safe.
11. Weirdly, the server "parses" `args`, and provides an optional default value BUT it never uses that. Instead, it uses `argv[1]` without checking `argc` at all. Oops.

That all aside, now comes the confusing part: how did you want the values to be written? This is not correct:

```
std::vector<ba::const_buffer> msg{
    ba::buffer(&filePacketSize_, sizeof(uint16_t)),
    ba::buffer(&filePacket_.val, sizeof(filePacket_.val)),
    ba::buffer(&filePacket_.values, sizeof(filePacket_.values))};
```

`values` is a `std::vector<>` so you cannot hope to use it in a bitwise way. It'll just invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Besides, it's pretty unclear why `filePacketSize_` is being written (it's never even assigned, or even initialized to a determinate value).

On the client side you read a `responseSize` as if one would be sent... Maybe you want to keep those two in sync.

---

## Suggested Appraoch

I'd do away with the separate size value(s), since a vector *already keeps track of that*. I'd also make sure your processData doesn't always `push_back` because the vector would always keep growing.

I'd make a protocol that actually sends the message size before the message itself, and makes sure it's correct.

Let's also make the random data naturally printable (a..z) for simplicity:

```
void processData()
{
    // Just for demonstration, we fill the vector with random characters
    std::mt19937 re(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> dist('a', 'z');
    filePacket_.values.clear();
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(filePacket_.values), properties_.val1,
                    [&] { return dist(re); });
}
```

Then in writing, let's do:

```
processData();

size_t length[] { filePacket_.values.size() };

std::vector<ba::const_buffer> msg{
    ba::buffer(length),
    ba::buffer(filePacket_.values)};
```

> Note how, again, we avoid manually specifying any buffer sizes. Also, we let
> the library figure out that `values` is a vector of POD elements and do the
> math to convert the calculate the correct start address and buffer size for the
> element data.

On the client side, we do the inverse:

```
size_t length = 0;
ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(&length, sizeof(length)));

response.values.resize(length);
ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(response.values));
```

(Here we can't avoid writing `sizeof(length)` without getting more clumsy than I'd like).

### Full Demo

- File `ipc_common.hpp`

  ```
   // File: ipc_common.hpp
   #include <cstdint>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <string>
   #include <vector>

   struct propertiesPacket {
       uint8_t val1;
       uint8_t val2;
   };

   struct processedData {
       std::vector<uint8_t> values;
   };
  ```
- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <vector>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <random>

   #include "ipc_common.hpp"

   namespace ba = boost::asio;
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::system::error_code;
   using TCPSocket = tcp::socket;

   class ServerConnection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ServerConnection> {
     public:
       ServerConnection(TCPSocket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket))
       {
       }

       void start()
       {
           std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
           doRead();
       }

     private:
       void doRead()
       {
           std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
           auto self(shared_from_this());
           socket_.async_read_some(
               ba::buffer(&properties_, sizeof(properties_)),
               [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                   std::clog << "received " << length << std::endl;
                   if (!ec) {
                       processData();

                       size_t length[] { filePacket_.values.size() };

                       std::vector<ba::const_buffer> msg{
                           ba::buffer(length), ba::buffer(filePacket_.values)};

                       ba::async_write(socket_, msg,
                                       [this, self = shared_from_this()](
                                           error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                                           std::clog << "written " << length
                                                     << std::endl;
                                           if (!ec)
                                               doRead();
                                       });
                   }
               });
       }

           void processData()
           {
               // Just for demonstration, we fill the vector with random characters
               std::mt19937 re(std::random_device{}());
               std::uniform_int_distribution<uint8_t> dist('a', 'z');
               filePacket_.values.clear();
               std::generate_n(back_inserter(filePacket_.values), properties_.val1,
                               [&] { return dist(re); });
           }

       TCPSocket socket_;

       propertiesPacket properties_;
       processedData    filePacket_;
   };

   class Server {
     public:
       using IOContext   = ba::io_context;
       using TCPAcceptor = tcp::acceptor;

       Server(IOContext& io, uint16_t port)
           : socket_(io)
           , acceptor_(io, {tcp::v4(), port})
       {
           doAccept();
       }

     private:
       void doAccept()
       {
           std::clog << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
           acceptor_.async_accept(socket_, [this](error_code ec) {
               if (!ec) {
                   std::clog << "Accepted " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                   std::make_shared<ServerConnection>(std::move(socket_))->start();
                   doAccept();
               } else {
                   std::clog << "Accept " << ec.message() << std::endl;
               }
           });
       }

       TCPSocket   socket_;
       TCPAcceptor acceptor_;
   };

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

       switch (args.size()) {
           case 1: args.push_back("6869"); break;
           case 2: break;
           default:
               std::clog << "usage: " << args.at(0) << " [port = 6869]" << std::endl;
               return 1;
       }

       try {
           ba::io_context io;
           Server server(io, std::stoi(args.at(1)));

           io.run();
       } catch (std::exception const &e) {
           std::clog << e.what() << std::endl;
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```
- File `client.cpp`

  ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>

   #include "ipc_common.hpp"

   namespace ba = boost::asio;
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       ba::io_context io;

       std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

       switch (args.size()) {
           case 1: args.push_back("localhost"); [[fallthrough]];
           case 2: args.push_back("6869");      [[fallthrough]];
           case 3: args.push_back("42");        [[fallthrough]];
           case 4: args.push_back("99");        [[fallthrough]];
           case 5: break;
           default:
               std::clog << "usage: " << args.at(0)
                         << " [host = localhost] [port = 6869] [val1=42] [val2=99]"
                         << std::endl;
               return 1;
       }

       try {
           propertiesPacket properties;
           properties.val1 = std::stoul(args.at(3));
           properties.val2 = std::stoul(args.at(4));

           tcp::socket   socket(io);
           tcp::resolver resolver(io);

           connect(socket, resolver.resolve({args.at(1), args.at(2)}));
           write(socket, ba::buffer(&properties, sizeof(properties)));

           processedData response{};
           {
               size_t length = 0;
               ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(&length, sizeof(length)));

               response.values.resize(length);
           }

           std::clog << "client response size: " << response.values.size() << std::endl;
           ba::read(socket, ba::buffer(response.values));

           std::clog.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(response.values.data()),
                           response.values.size()) << "\n";
           // return 0;
       } catch (std::exception &e) {
           std::clog << e.what() << std::endl;
           return 1;
       }
   }
  ```

Demo output:

[image]

## Portability

You should probably keep byte ordering in mind as well. You could consider using JSON or another Well Known serialization format.

Comment: I'm so sorry about the typos, when porting this to be self contained, I must've forgotten to change some things They are fixed now, not that it matters as you already answered my question. And for that thank you very much! :)